# For skew symmetric matrices the trace is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $A$ is skew symmetric, then $Tr(A) = 0$.

Proof:

We have since $A = - A^T$

$$ Tr(A) = Tr(A^T)= Tr(-A) = - Tr(A) \implies 2 Tr(A) = 0 \implies Tr(A) = 0$$

Is this correct?

Does it follow also that $|A| = 0 $?

Comment: $\det(-A) = (-1)^nA$ when $A$ is of size $n\times n$, so it only follows that $\det A=0$ if $A$ is odd-dimensional.

Comment: Yes the proof is correct. And not necessary singular. You might be thinking about matrices over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It should not be difficult to find a skew symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix whose determinant is not zero... Have you even tried?